# How to keep the foam backing in place, to fix a gap by bathroom faucet

Tags: repair, faucet, caulk, gap, foam

There is a large-ish gap by the bathtub faucet.

[image: gap behind faucet]

I planned to do it myself, without having to remove any plumbing parts (which is out of my ability level). I bought foam backing rod, which I plan to put in a circle around the gap, and then caulk over that. But how to keep the "donut" of foam in place? And also, is this a stupid idea that will leave an ugly lumpy mess?

[image: foam backing]

Comment: You've asked an [XY question](http://xyproblem.info), about your proposed solution rather than the problem. Your solution is far from ideal. I suggest you revise your post to ask about the problem.

Comment: And unless you have moderate physical disability, this is about as basic a plumbing challenge as you can get. I would fix it right.

Comment: I just screwed in my spout all the way and didn't worry about adding any foam or caulking.

Comment: Foam backing rod keeps itself in place just by friction, and it is sized large enough so that compressing it into the gap generates that friction. That said, your gap is FAR too large to be remedied with caulk. Someone needs to remove and reinstall that spout correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Forget the foam and caulk.  Try using a [universal spout kit.](https://www.lowes.com/pd/Keeney/5013546739?cm_mmc=shp-_-c-_-prd-_-bth-_-ggl-_-PLA_BTH_225_Faucets-Showerheads-And-Bath-Decor-_-5013546739-_-online-_-0-_-0&gclid=CjwKCAjw-7OlBhB8EiwAnoOEk2Yv62vG0ErBk8kkyzHglF5OcjrCqiPlx-M37JT3lkdHNGzvdUZnxxoCaOUQAvD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds)

The hardest part will be getting the old spout off.  It either is threaded on to a 1/2" or 3/4" male stub or it is held on with a saddle type clamp and O-rings over a 1/2" pipe.

To unthread turn the spout counter clock-wise.

If it will not turn use a mirror or take a pic with your phone of the underside.  You will see an opening with a screw (usually Allen head).
You need to loosen the screw quite a bit and then try to turn the spout and pull at the same time.

Once off refer to the instructions included with the kit to reinstall the new spout so that it fits to the wall with no gap.

Once you do this you will be amazed at how easy it really can be. You also can brag to your neighbors.